# FormView get_context_data does not work when form is invalid

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

When creating a view using **FormView** class and using **get_context_data** to display some data on the test html page alongside the form ,
Error is received when the form gets invalid , and context data is not retrieved

> in get_context_data
>
> context['username'] = data['username']
> KeyError: 'username'

Key Error is thrown when the form invalidates

```
class TestView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = TestForm
    template_name = 'test.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CredentialsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            data = TestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})(self.request).data
            context['username'] = data['username']
            context['firstname'] = data['firstname']
            context['lastname'] = data['lastname']
            
        return context

        
    def form_valid(self, form):
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.query_api(password)
        else:
            return super(TestView, self).form_valid(form)
```

here is the traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 34, in inner response = get_response(request) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 115, in _get_response  response =
> self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 113, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request,
> *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
> line 71, in view return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py",
> line 52, in dispatch  return super().dispatch(request, *args,
> **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
> line 97, in dispatch return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)  File
> "./ssh/views.py", line 91, in post return self.form_invalid(form,
> **kwargs) File "./ssh/views.py", line 77, in form_invalid context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs) File "./ssh/views.py", line 97, in
> get_context_data  kwargs['username'] = data['username'] KeyError:
> 'username'

In the Scenario Above ,

- How can we get the context data when the form is invalid ?
- How can we send the form errors back to html page when the form is
  invalid ?

Answer (score 1):

get_context_data is called before your form_valid function.

On the loading of the page you try to fetch the value of data["username"] while it's still not completed.

Basically :
GET on your View
-> get_context_data is called --> The form isn't completed yet

You could get your args on a post function.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = TestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Do Stuff
    else:
        # Something else
        return render(ThePageWithTheForm)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more , i am looking to send the form errors when the form is invalid to  the html page

Comment: You can override the post() function which is fired when you submit your form. 
Inside its request, you have access to request.BODY, which contains all informations of your form. 
The username you're looking for is inside it.

Comment: I tried post method but it then does not use the form_valid function

Comment: I suggest you add `form = request.POST' and check if form.is_valid().

Comment: I was looking for a clean structure using formview class , putting all content in the post method makes it bulky

Comment: I just call whatever function I need from there, but surely there are other ways to go about this ! If you find something that satisfies you, then I'd be happy to learn as well.